# Что означает -y при установке в apt-get

Tags: linux, apt-get

Имеется команда `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`, для чего нужен параметр -у?

Comment: Я даже вот такое вброшу: `man apt-get | grep -A 4 -- -y`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Без него apt-get задает уточняющий вопрос - "вы действительно хотите это установить?"

Так что ключ нужен для "ускорения" установки на одно нажатие Enter.

Answer (score 4):

Разве так тяжело обратиться к гуглу? Но даже не это беспокоит больше. Можно даже не к гуглу, а к man.

Почитайте, пожалуйста:

```
man man 
man apt-get
http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html
```

в

> man apt-get

прямым текстом пишут:

```
   -y, --yes, --assume-yes
       Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
       run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
       changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
       package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
       abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
```

А в гугле в первой же ссылке:
https://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=apt-get&category=8

```
-y, --yes, --assume-yes
Автоматически отвечать "да" в ответ на запрос программы; на все запросы,
которые будет выводить программа будет автоматически выдаваться ответ "да".
При возникновении нежелательной ситуации, как то: изменения пакета в состоянии
удержания или удаления необходимого для работы системы пакета, apt-get будет
аварийно завершать свою работу. 
Элемент настройки: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
```